# Are there infinitely many primes such that $4\notin\langle 6,8\rangle $?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $p\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $\langle 6,8\rangle$ denotes the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ generated by $6,8$. Is there any way to prove or disprove that:

There are infinitely many primes $p\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ such that $4\notin\langle 6,8\rangle$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you have a list of the first few primes satisfying your condition?

Comment: You have $\langle 6,16\rangle$ in the title and $\langle 6,8\rangle$ in the text.

Comment: @YCor Thanks. I have corrected this typo.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ is a field. What subgroup do yo want to have, additive or multiplicative?

Comment: @Piquito $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field; $\mathbb Z^*_p$ is its multiplicative group. (In the additive group, the question would be trivial, as $4=6+6-8$.)

Comment: @Piquito Of course a multiplicative group.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{6},\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_{15})$. This is Galois with Galois group the semi direct product of $(\mathbf{Z}/15)^*$ by $(\mathbf{Z}/3)^2$. By Cebotarev, there are infinitely many primes whose a Frobenius is the element which is trivial in the quotient and is the order three element which fixes the first cube root and not the second. The fact that the Frobenius is trivial in the quotient implies that $p \equiv 1 \mod 15$, and the other property implies that $6$ is a cube module $p$ but $2$ (and thus $4$) is not. But now $4$ can’t be in the group generated by $6$ and $8$ since the latter are cubes. Hence there exist a positive density of such primes p.

The inverse is also true since if $p \not\equiv 1 \mod 3$ then $2$ and thus $4$ is already generated by $8$.

Comment: What do you mean by quotient, please? I am lack of the knowlege appearing in your answer, so I read some materials after reading your answer. But I still can't understand your answer well. Would you explain it in detail please?

Comment: If you don’t know how to compute the Galois group of $F$ as a semi-direct product then I won’t be able to explain what a Frobenius element is let alone the Cebotarev density theorem. Plus, I am on an iPhone. The details are all there.